# Layout with tiles of 2 types

Tags: javascript, css, layout, responsive-design

Is there a way to make this kind of layout with pure CSS or CSS + little JS? (click my avatar to enlarge reference image =)
My attempts to use floats and display options haven't succeed. `See`
http://jsfiddle.net/vdk2wns1/1/

Tiles will be used for images and iframes.

p.s. using external code (like Masonry or Isotope) is not appropriate here.

Comment: Your avatar has 1 large block and a bunch of smaller ones. Is the large block the other type? Your Fiddle has only one type of block.

Comment: That is correct. One big block and 12 small. May be you don't see that big one  because of @media. If you set viewport width larger than 640px you'll see it. Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solve my problem after @bobdye shared his idea.
The final code (jsfiddle) is: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexFromMoscow/vdk2wns1/23/)
The solution appeared in 4 steps:
(1). style large block with `float: right;`
(2). `clear` float of the second small block;
(3). set up negative `margins` for large block while in 3-cloumn layout;
(4). make some adjusments to @media queries.
Hope this will help someone else =)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be:

```
    #container {
        max-width: 860px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .block {
        width: 23%;
        height: 200px;
        background: #ccc;
        margin: 10px 1%;
        float: left; 
        outline: 1px solid red;
    }
    .block:nth-of-type(3) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .block:nth-of-type(5) {
        float: right;
        width: 48%;
        height: 420px;
        margin-top: -210px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
        .block:nth-of-type(3) {
            clear: none;
        }
        .block:nth-of-type(5) {
            float: left;
            width: 23%;
            height: 200px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    }
```

Since it appears you wanted to adapt to different screen sizes, I changed the widths to percentages to make it responsive. [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/k85w7oh5/) shows the result.

If you didn't want to float Block 5 right, you could position it absolutely.

I expect that you can adapt the basic ideas to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help @bobdye . You gave me the key for solving my issue. I'll post my solution in a separate post. Cheers.